# rails 3.2 LESS CSS and heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, less

Wanted to try something new, using the awesome [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and their [Less CSS](http://lesscss.org/). I finally got my app up and running, but it crashed at heroku's read-only system. 
I'm trying to figure out my options, using LESS, rails 3.2 and heroku. This is what I think can do:

(1) One option is: precompile.

```
 bundle exec rake assets:precompile
 git commit public/assets -m "tedious precompilation task"
 git push heroku
```

I'll surely forget to precompile once, just push the changes to heroku and piss off my users. Not what I want.

(2) A good option is `less.js`. It compiles client-side. Is this what most use?

(3) A better option, IMO. Precompile to cache. Neither a precompile routine nor extra client side work. What I'm asking, is there something like *hassle for SASS*, for less?

**UPDATE 26th jan-12:** people don't use hassle rails 3.1+, they use sass-rails (default rails 3.2) with the asset pipeline. hassle is sooo rails 3.0 ;) The rake precompile step failed at heroku. **/UPDATE**

I find the idea of compiling to static rack cache to be served by varnish absolutely brilliant. I'd prefer it over having every client needing to compile my less css themselves when it can be done one time, at deploy.

**UPDATE 25th jan:** Updating myself on heroku. The cedar stack supports the asset pipeline, so there is no need for the hassle gem anymore. Correct? **/UPDATE**

What to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
application.rb
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Simple solution, once you know it .... !

Use with `gem less-rails`
Now all assets are compiled and will be cached, (as in option 3). The asset pipeline is awesome!

Problem background:

Heroku couldn't precompile as rails pr default tries to initialize and attach to DB, but the ENV vars ain't available yet. **Without** it you'd get

```
$ git push heroku

Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
Running: rake assets:precompile
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Just as a note: Heroku has a way of providing the environment variables at precompile stage too.

```
$ heroku plugins:install http://github.com/heroku/heroku-labs.git
$ heroku labs:enable user_env_compile  [--app my_app]
```

Comment: I do not think the plugin part of your answer applies anymore, I cannot seem to get it to push via that route. Heroku also warns each command that the 'The plugin heroku-labs has been deprecated', which I think may be the reason why

Comment: @Crimbo thanks. You're probably right. I don't use this anymore myself. perhaps there is a different approach to installing 'heroku labs', or another way to enable env vars at an earlier stage. Let me know if you find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You have gem:

```
gem 'less-rails'
```

If you add it to your `Gemfile` then you can use your `.less` files the same way as `.scss` and `.sass`.

**EDIT**
But if you want use Bootstrap then it is even easier:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

And then

```
rails g bootstrap:install
```

More info at [GitHub repo](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/)

Comment: I'm using this gem already. How do you deploy to heroku with it? Am I missing some configurations?

Comment: this above is `less-rails`. I can use the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` to install the precompiled bootstrap CSS (?) and avoid the problem. But the goal is to develop using Less. Do you have any app on heroku using Less?

Comment: Yes I have on Cedar stack. I've precompile all assets before pushing and it's work great for me. You can check at http://tori-app.herokuapp.com (sorry, but app is in polish, but design and CSS code is language agnostic but minified).

Comment: so you're doing option 1. precompile -> commit -> push.

Comment: Ya, but you must remember to add precompiled assets to your git repo. It's also prefered way for Heroku and any other host. If you do that on your machine, then you don't need to install additional gems, it's faster and it's use less resources.

Comment: When manually precompiling, you need them in git. But I disagree with this approach, compiled assets don't belong in git. Automate it! See my answer.